# The schema master did not complete a replication cycle after the last reboot

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I'm attempting to add a Windows Server 2012 Domain Controller to an Existing Windows Server 2003 network, and then following that, will migrate it to be the domain master.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2013/05/05/step-by-step-adding-a-windows-server-2012-domain-controller-to-an-existing-windows-server-2003-network/) and then will be going through [this one](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2014/04/01/step-by-step-active-directory-migration-from-windows-server-2003-to-windows-server-2012-r2/).

When I reach the actual execution (either via the wizard or in PowerShell), I receive the following error:

```
 Install-ADDSDomainController : Verification of prerequisites for
 Active Directory preparation failed. The schema master did not
 complete a replication cycle after the last reboot. At line:1 char:1
 + Install-ADDSDomainController `
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-ADDSDomainController], TestFailedException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Test.VerifyADPrepPrerequisites.ADPrep.General.0,Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Deployment.PowerShell.Commands.InstallADDSDomainControllerCommand
```

So far I've not found an answer to this.  I've tried this with multiple accounts that should have proper permissions (groups) granted, but no luck.

This user is a member of the following groups:

[image: group memberships]

What's happening here?

Comment: What does running 'repadmin /showrepl' on the Schema Master return?

Comment: @Mike1980 https://gist.github.com/ylluminate/c22cc38823faf8629569aeaa2bc2981f

Comment: It looks like you have some DNS lookup issues there. How about a 'dcdiag /test:dns'. Do you have any DCs that have failed in the past and/or not been removed from AD correctly?